# downgrading an angular component for use in angularjs context does not render

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs

I have followed most of the articles and SO posts to achieve the base/standard bootstrapping of an angularJS app ready for migration.

```
import { DoBootstrap, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {downgradeComponent, UpgradeModule} from '@angular/upgrade/static';
import * as angular from 'angular';
import { setAngularJSGlobal } from '@angular/upgrade/static';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { IncompleteAddressesComponent } from "./incomplete-addresses/incomplete-addresses.component";
import app from '../../angularJs/src/app/index.module.ajs';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [BrowserModule, UpgradeModule, RouterOutlet, IncompleteAddressesComponent],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [],
})
export class AppModule implements DoBootstrap {
  constructor(private upgrade: UpgradeModule) {}
  ngDoBootstrap() {
    setAngularJSGlobal(angular);
    // port Angular Environment constants into 1.x AngularJs (deprecates Constants Loader)
    loadConstantsIntoAngularJS();

    this.upgrade.bootstrap(document.documentElement, ['app'], {
      strictDi: true,
    });

    app.directive('incompleteAddresses', downgradeComponent({component: IncompleteAddressesComponent}) as angular.IDirectiveFactory);
  }
}

// TODO: [deprecate] angularJS dependency
function loadConstantsIntoAngularJS() {
  const ngConstants = angular.module('app.constants', []);
  Object.entries(environment.constants).forEach(([name, value]) =>
    ngConstants.constant(name, value)
  );
  console.log(environment.constants);
}
```

my Angular component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'incomplete-addresses',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './incomplete-addresses.component.html',
  styleUrl: './incomplete-addresses.component.css',
})
export class IncompleteAddressesComponent {
  constructor() {
    console.log("AAA: here");
  }
}
```

just using it like `<incomplete-addresses>` in the angularJS template where I want to include it.

The issue is I can see in the DOM the angular element but not the content of the incomplete-addresses template (which for testing I've simply put `<div>Hello</div>`)

I would expect to see in the console log the "AAA:here" but I don't.
Somehow this component doesn't seem to be initialising ... please let me know if there's anything else you need to see.

I also have this in an entry file:

```
platformBrowserDynamic()
  .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

I get no console errors either.

Comment: my thoughts were to do with it being a standalone component cos most of those articles were orientated around a module, so I did try and declare it through the ngModule rather then importing it. Same result

Comment: another thing might be that the incomplete-addresses component is being included in a template that was eventually rendered from ui-router in the ui-view angularjs directive.

Answer (score 0):

not sure of the underlying mechanism, but I was bootstrapping the angularJs app and then adding the downgraded component.

The solution:

add all modules first then bootstrap the app